RoR Mobility translation: mass migrate translated attribute
Using Mobility (table backend), how to use ActiveRecord relations to migrate up/down a previously untranslated attribute? Ideally with a single query, not iterating through records.
Mobility.configure do |config|
  config.plugins do
    backend :table
    active_record
    reader
    writer
    backend_reader
    query
    cache
    dirty
    presence
  end
end

class Content < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility
  default_scope { i18n }
  translates :free # <-- This gets added, so a migration is needed
end

class LocalizeContentFree < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.2]
  def change
    add_column :content_translations, :free, :boolean, default: false, null: false

    # This works using raw SQL, how to use AR relations instead?
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        execute <<-SQL
          UPDATE content_translations
          SET free = contents.free
          FROM contents
          WHERE contents.id = content_translations.content_id
        SQL
      end
      dir.down do
        execute <<-SQL
          UPDATE contents
          SET free = content_translations.free
          FROM content_translations
          WHERE contents.id = content_translations.content_id
        SQL
      end
    end

    remove_column :contents, :free, :boolean, default: false, null: false
  end
end


Other than the fact that this migration does not appear to be appropriately reversible (e.g. add_column will become remove column and vise versa but your migrations rely on the existence of these columns) the amount of effort (and code) necessary to create those update statements is unlikely to result in anything better or more maintainable than the raw SQL you have posted now.
